# RxJava android: observe every string in array that dynamically changes?

Tags: java, android, arrays, rx-java2

I have something like this:

```
mStringList = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        mStringList.add(i + "");
        Log.d(TAG, "iterration " + i );
    }
```

I need to observe this `ArrayList` with RxJava. How can I create an `Observable` and subscribe to it, so I can see every element that is added to the `ArrayList`?

I want to see something like this in my console:

```
console -> iterration 0;
console -> observer 0;
console -> iterration 1;
console -> observer 1;
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Even if you'r looking for a RxJava Solution there's no need doing that, because android provide its own methods/classes to handle that.

First there's Android-Architecture-Components [LiveData](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/livedata.html).

For this you have `ObservableList` and `ObservableArrayList`.

Since you want to listen for changes you can use the new [DiffUtil](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/util/DiffUtil.html) class which does exactly what you are looking for.

If you still want to use RXJava you can use another attempt doing that like:

```
PublishSubject<String> sub = PublishSubject.create();
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
public void addDataToList(String str) { 
  list.add(str);  
  sub.onNext(str);
}
```

and finally observe on your subject.

```
sub.subscribe( next -> { .. }, error -> {  });
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, in my case i have an List that populates from outside, and i want to observe every String, that added to it. I tried do it by Flowable and Consumer and it works, but result is console -> iterration 0;console -> iterration 1;... console -> iterration last; and than -
console -> observer 0;
console -> observer 1;

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, you have to do only one action:

```
Observable.from(mStringList).subscribe(/*onNext Action here*/, /*onError Action here*/, /*onComplete Action here*/)
```

Thats all.

Comment: Thanks for answer. I tried this at beginning, as it is basicks of rx, but my "OnNext" method never call, only "onCompleted", when it subscribed, and i get console-> observer:"onComplete", than : console-> iterration 0 ...console-> iterration last.